Can a new subdivision be built off of an exiting private road when the only access to this new subdivision will be the private road?
They are looking to build a 6 lot subdivision in my neighborhood.  This subdivision will include a new private road.  The problem is that the only access to this new subdivision will be another private street.  Can you add one private road off of an already existing private road. There will be no access to a public way from this subdivision and the only way on and off this new road will be the existing private way.

What exactly does a private street mean in this case? Does it mean that sub division is responsible for maintenance of the road or does it mean they can control who has access? From my understanding it just means that they have to pay for maintenance of it.

The original road they want to connect to is listed as an unaccepted part of the road.  The titles say that the residents have the right to use the road as it gives access to the accepted part of the road.  The new subdivision will build a private road off this unaccepted part of the street and the subdivision will have control over upkeep of that street.

I think you misunderstood what I am asking, there is a difference in a private road that is private in terms of who pays for maintenance costs and a private road for use in a gated community with limited access. In the last couple of states/cities I lived in there are plenty of private roads that are fully open to the public but are maintained by private groups.

The new road will be maintained by the residents who purchase the houses on that road.  The town will not take care or do any maintenance on it.  As for travel purpose of the new road there will be none as it is a dead end.  We are being told the old street that they want to tie into is an unaccepted street by the town they are now listing it as private. (deeds just say the residents have use of the road for what is intended for. )

That information should be edited into your question as it is relevant and useful for providing an answer but that sounds like your answer as it is private for purposes of maintenance and not for access. As a note my city has done things such as issue a levy tax on people in the area around a road when they need to do major maintenance on it.

Jurisdiction will certainly matter here, but here in Florida that this sort of thing is somewhat common.  Subdivisions that want to have gated communities have private roads.  The subdivision is responsible for the upkeep of roads on the secured side of the gate, and residents have deeded access to the private roads.  Residents are allowed to grant access to those they choose such as maintenance personal and visitors.
In the situation you cite, it is likely that owners of the new homes will be granted access to both the new private road and the existing.  Otherwise how will the builder sell such homes?
It may be that the owner of the existing private road had granted access to the existing private road as part of the condition of sale to the developer.

No one on the existing private road has been asked to grant access as part of the condition of sales to the developer.

@privateuser The owner of the existing private road may not be a resident on the existing private road.

@privateuser, adding to the other comment, residents using an easement on land owned by someone else don't have to give their permission for another easement to be granted. They may not like the additional traffic, but if they don't own the land they are just another user of the easement granted by the landowner.

@privateuser depending on your jurisdiction, the new residents or the builder cannot access that property via the private road.  Doing so is trespassing and probably needs law enforcement involvement.
